# Google Play Services Unity Plugin not Show Leaderboard

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am building a game for Android with Unity 5, and I have imported this [plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)

But it's not working properly I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmHXl-UFTqM) :

When I try to post or show leaderboard , it does not show anything .It does not even throw  any error. Sign-in and out are working properly.Please help

Code :

```
public void LogIn ()
{
    Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) =>
    {
        if (success) {
            Debug.Log ("Login Sucess");
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("Login failed");
        }
    });
}

public void LogOut ()
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SignOut ();
}

public void Post ()
{

    if (Social.localUser.authenticated) {
        Social.ReportScore (5000, LeaderbordId, (bool success) =>
        {
            if (success) {
                ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI (LeaderbordId);
            } else {
                Debug.Log ("Add Score Fail");
            }
        });
    } 
}

public void ShowLeader ()
{

    Social.ShowLeaderboardUI ();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if i got what you want. I think you are trying to open leaderboards everytime you post a score. I'll change your script to make it easier to understand.

When you are using Google Play Services Pluggin you need a few things to get started. Make sure you have this. On the top of the script you'll write:

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
```

Then you'll need to add this to your start function:

```
void Start(){
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
}
```

It's easier if you make an function just to show your leaderboards, like your last function for example:

```
public void ShowLB(){
    ((PlayGamesPlatform) Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI("YOUR_LEADERBOARDS_ID_HERE");
}
```

Then your Post () function would be like this:

```
public void Post (){

    if (Social.localUser.authenticated) {
        Social.ReportScore (5000, LeaderbordId, (bool success) =>
        {
            if (success) {
                ShowLB ();
            } else {
                Debug.Log ("Add Score Fail");
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

And it seems like in your last function you might want to do this:

```
public void ShowAchievs(){
    Social.ShowAchievementsUI ();
}
```

Otherwise it should be like this:

```
public void ShowLB(){
    ((PlayGamesPlatform) Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI("YOUR_LEADERBOARDS_ID_HERE");
}
```

But it's WAY MORE EASY if you just use your post function after a trigger, like the end of the game, and use something else to show your LB. Like a click on a button or something.

I don't know that's what you wanted.

Comment: I did all this and tried in some other ways to... but it still not showing the leaderbord..thx for try :)

Comment: is it necessary to publish game before using these....because I didn't published it yet.

Comment: it's not necessary. but you need your Google Play Service ID tho. Make sure you followed this steps: 1) Get the google play services ID under your app name in services on Publisher's console. 2) Set up your project with your app id by going under Window -> Google Play Service -> Android and adding you app id , 3) Link your application and sign it using this method: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html (if you are not using android studio, you might want to use  "Signing your app manually" on the botton of the page.)

Comment: If you are still having problems, check the log file (seen by running adb logcat) and there will be log messages that will point to the source of the . problem.

Comment: I did all @VitorFigueredo

Comment: OK, i think the only things i didn't told you to do are: 1) i THINK that you need 5 achievments before doing this, 2) Did you downloaded Services on your SDK Manager? 3) Your bundle id in unity is the same as you entered in Google Play Services? 4) Try doing like the video, creating a button just to post something to your leaderboards, for test of course, and other button to open the leaderboards. 5) This is personal, but i use google play services commands like this: Social.ReportScore(score, LeaderBoards1, (bool success) => {}); without anything within the "{}" you could try.

Comment: I think i giured it out what might be happening, ahaha. I had the same problem today and i think it's because you were not using the official store version, so you need to sign the debug version as well. Do what's under "To get the debug certificate fingerprint:". You need to run this as admin on cmd inside java folder, the default path to debug is:  C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.android\debug.keystore and the default password is "android".

Answer (score 0):

You must be running your game inside **editor** , You need to run your game in an **actual device** or perhaps an emulator ( with a gmail account ... those are rare)

Here is the thing ... 
open a console , and type this

```
adb logcat
```

or you can narrow the result by filtering only logs from unity

```
adb logcat -s Unity
```

Open your game , look at at the console If you get

> ShowAchievementsUI not implemented

or

> ShowLeaderboardsUI not implemented

That only means that you are using the default configurations (The unity one)
I suggest you replace the defaults with [google play](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)'s

> The default configuration needs to be **replaced** with a custom configuration

```
    using GooglePlayGames;
    using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
    using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
        // enables saving game progress.
        .EnableSavedGames()
        // registers a callback to handle game invitations received while the game is not running.
        .WithInvitationDelegate(<callback method>)
        // registers a callback for turn based match notifications received while the
        // game is not running.
        .WithMatchDelegate(<callback method>)
        .Build();

    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    // recommended for debugging:
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    // Activate the Google Play Games platform
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
```

Any errors will now be shown in the console, actually you dont need all of that of it to work , you only need these

```
PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
```

for logging the errors , 
Then you can authenticate :)

If you open it and suddenly it crashes , it means that you have a problem in your manifest file

you probably going to need this if you using an **older version** (This get added automatically if you are using the latest version)

```
<application ... >
...
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
....
</application>
```

Make sure you update **google play services** to the latest one via the SDK Manager , that way you can avoid **unpleasant** situations

Cheers.

Comment: If Sign-in and out are working properly, he's not in the editor.